# Does lack of a curved taxi-line indicate a turn is not permitted?

Tags: ground-operations, taxiing, airport-markings, taxiways

Does the lack of a curved taxiway centerline between two taxiways indicate that a turn is not permitted?

Take for example the complex of taxiway connections at KATL here: 33.636153, -84.421919 ([see on google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@33.6363702,-84.4219846,221m/data=!3m1!1e3)). At this intersection, there are several connections between taxiways that don't have a curved line between them. See the attached image for specific examples.[image: taxilines example] Does this indicate that aircraft are not permitted to take this path, whether it's for operational, safety, logistical, or other reasons? If so, are there exceptions to these rules in certain circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, lack of a centerline stripe doesn't restrict a controller from assigning that routing, nor does it restrict a pilot from turning there.

The stripe might be omitted because "that" turn wasn't anticipated to be used often, but the stripes (or lack thereof) carry no regulatory authority.

Comment: For completeness, the example in the lower-left for instance is due to a nonstandard fillet, so the centerline marking is omitted intentionally to indicate judgemental oversteering is required. AC 150/5340-1